# Typescript Uncaught ReferenceError: notifyOwner is not defined

Tags: .net, typescript

I have a project where I just added a button with an onclick event and in my reviewservice.ts I then entered an function into ReviewService.ts. When I build the project and click the button I am getting notifyOwner is not defined is there anything page where I need to move the function?

ReviewPage.html

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="notifyOwner(reviewer)">Review Complete</button>
</div>
```

In ReviewService.ts

```
notifyOwner(reviewerId: number): Observable<void> {
    let data: NotifyReviewerRequest = {
        ReviewerId: reviewerId
    };

    return this.http
        .post(this.apiUrls.NotifyReviewer, data, this.options)
        .catch(this.errorHandler)
        .map(response => undefined);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the function to the corresponding component or call a different function in your component that uses your service.

and make sure that your component contains:

```
templateUrl: 'ReviewPage.html
```

html files can only reach the functions that are in .ts files contains the  `templateUrl: 'ReviewPage.html`.

other way is that you can add service to your component file, then call user service function in that file.